# Logging into a PHP Application with OAuth2

Tags: php, android, json, symfony, oauth-2.0

I currently have a PHP web-based application (built with `Symfony2` using `FOSUserbundle` and `FOSOAuthServerBundle`). I'm currently trying to have my server authenticate the user attempting to log in from their mobile device (Android) and send back an `access token` and a `refresh token`.

Ideally, the outcome is: The user enters their canonical username and password into the client (mobile app), the user is authenticated, the server responds with an access token and a refresh token. The user gains access to information that only pertains to them. (I'm not certain if an implicit grant or a password flow makes more sense here)

So far, I've managed to receive a response from the server, but I always get a JSON response stating: Invalid Request. To be more precise:

`Error: org.json.JSONException: Value {"error_description":"Invalid grant_type parameter or parameter missing","error":"invalid_request"} of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray`

I'm not sure if my frame of thinking is wrong or not. In any case, here's my code. Let me know if you need more. Thanks.

```
private class validateUser extends AsyncTask<String, String, Void> {

    private ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    String result = "";

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressDialog.setMessage("Logging In...");
        progressDialog.show();
        progressDialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
            public void onCancel(DialogInterface arg0) {
                validateUser.this.cancel(true);
                Log.e("Process","Cancelled");
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String...params) {
        String username = loginUsername.getText().toString();
        String password = loginPassword.getText().toString();

        String baseUrl = "HOST.local";
        String token = "oauth/v2/token?";
        String client_id = "client_id=CLIENT_ID";
        String client_secret = "&client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET";
        String grant_type = "&grant_type=password&username=";


        String url = baseUrl + token + client_id + client_secret + grant_type + username + "&password=" + password;

        httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        httpContext = new BasicHttpContext();
        response = null;


        try {
            httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            entity = response.getEntity();

            inputStream = entity.getContent();
        }
        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
            Log.e("UnsupportedEncodingException", e1.toString());
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (ClientProtocolException e2) {
            Log.e("ClientProtocolException", e2.toString());
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IllegalStateException e3) {
            Log.e("IllegalStateException", e3.toString());
            e3.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e4) {
            Log.e("IOException", e4.toString());
            e4.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            String line = null;
            while ((line = bReader.readLine()) != null) {
                sBuilder.append(line + "\n");
            }

            inputStream.close();
            result = sBuilder.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("StringBuilding & BufferedReader", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        Log.e("Response", httpPost.toString());

        return null;

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void v) {
        //parse JSON data
        Integer i;
        try {
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            for(i=0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject jObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                String access_token = jObject.getString("access_token");
                int expires_in = jObject.getInt("expires_in");
                String token_type = jObject.getString("token_type");
                String scope = jObject.getString("scope");
                String refresh_token = jObject.getString("refresh_token");


            } // End Loop
            this.progressDialog.dismiss();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSONException", "Error: " + e.toString());
        } // catch (JSONException e)
    } // protected void onPostExecute(Void v)

}
```

Comment: You are setting query parameters and POST data and then sending as a POST request to the server.  Is the server even handling your query params if you make a post request? Have you tried sending GET request with query params?

Comment: @atastrumf I've tried both POST and GET commands. Both have returned the same response.